# Network Policy not working correctly, Not able to curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-networkpolicy

This is my network policy. I am applying in EKS using calico plugin

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: net-document
  namespace: default
spec:
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  - Ingress
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-document
  ingress:
  - {}
  egress:
  - to:
    ports:
    - port: 53
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 53
      protocol: UDP
    - port: 5000
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 5000
      protocol: UDP
    - port: 27017
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 443
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 443
      protocol: UDP
    - port: 6379
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 80
      protocol: UDP
    - port: 5672
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 943
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 1194
      protocol: TCP
```

But when I go inside the pod and do

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

I am getting timeout error. It should run as I have allowed port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Your pod does not have permissions to call the AWS API as it says in the error.

Make sure the correct prefix list is whitelisted on 443

Comment: Pods have permission. When I remove the network policy which means I open the egress to all ports then everything works perfectly. what ports do I need open for AWS API??

Comment: Just HTTPS.  S3 ips are always publicly routeable even if you have a VPC Gateway/Endpoint.  Their prefix will need to be whitelisted.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html#vpc-endpoints-security